# Build Android APK programmatically

Tags: android, linux, command-line, apk, builder

I need to build a web environment which creates signed Android .apk files from a given Android application source code. How can I get this? The web environment will be running on a Linux machine.

I was thinking on a Linux shell script which builds signed .apk file. However, I've read some information about Apache Ant but I don't understand exactly its purpose and if it could do the trick.

Comment: Ant automates the building of a project. Once you have a `build.xml` file in your project, you can just run `ant build` from the command line. This is a great tutorial: http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-ant-to-automate-building-android.html